# (Rails 4, acts_as_taggable_on): Using dynamic context in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

acts_as_taggable_on is great and very easy to work with when using static contexts.
I'm trying however to store tags selected by the user in a context that depends on one of the model's attributes.

The model is `Ingredient` and it has an attribute `center_id`. I'd like the user to be able to select tags and their context to be a string based on that `center_id`.

I need help getting the right code for the controller and the view.

Model:

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :center
```

Helper:

```
module IngredientsHelper
  def get_all_tags_for_center
    return Ingredient.tags_on(get_tags_context)
  end

  def get_tags_context
    "c#{@ingredient.center_id}_ingredient"
  end
end
```

View - I tried this, but it may not be the right thing for dynamic contexts:

```
<%= f.association :tag_list do %>
<%= f.select :tag_list, options_for_select(get_tags, @ingredient.tag_list_on(get_tags_context)), {}, {class: 'doselect2', multiple: true } %>
    <% end %>
```

Controller - your help needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. For future readers:

Controller:

```
@ingredient.set_tag_list_on get_tags_context, params[:tags].join(",")
if @ingredient.update_attributes(ingredient_params)
  .
  .
end
```

View:

```
<%= select_tag "tags[]", options_for_select(get_tags, @ingredient.tag_list_on(get_tags_context)), class: 'doselect2', multiple: true  %>
```